# Verifying Veeam Backups per Server using Powershell

Tags: powershell, veeam

I can use Powershell and the Get-VBRBackup and Get-VBRJob commandlets to get the status of a back up job. But i want to verify an individual server has been backed up in the last 7 days. Is that possible with Powershell?

Comment: Yeah I tried their forum and they won't let me register with a Yahoo email address. I'm not giving them a real email.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest instead of using PowerShell, use [VeeamONE component](http://www.veeam.com/virtual-server-management-one-free.html) which has reporting tool included. You could use a combination of 'Protected VMs' and 'VM Backup Status' reports and have them sent directly from VeeamONE to your email. Imho, it's very convenient.